# How can I compile the mainline Linux Kernel with the same compile flags Debian uses for hardening?

Tags: linux, build, compilation, kernel

As far as I understand, Debian uses several hardening options when building packages. But how do I find out *which compile flags are used for the Linux Kernel in Debian and for a specific architecture*?

I'm frequently building my own Kernel packages from the upstream mainline sources (kernel.org) and I would like to apply the same or at least similar hardening as Debian uses for its Kernel builds. The target architecture is arm (or armhf in Debian terms) and I'm crosscompiling on x86-64 (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 0):

Get the Debian source package for the kernel and grab the .config file in their kernel source root. Alternatively, if you have a running system, you can get its config at runtime by using `cat /proc/config` or `zcat /proc/config.gz` usually, if the kernel supports that. Alternately, use /boot/config-x-y-z

Once you have the config (this tells the kernel Makefile what components to build into the kernel and what modules to build) put it in the root directory of the kernel source you are building, name it ".config" and then run `make old config` in that directory. Then run `make menuconfig` to tweak if necessary

You can get the kernel source package using `apt-get source linux-source` or by downloading the .deb file manually from a Debian HTTP or FTP repository (check what's in your /etc/apt/sources.list)

If you get raw .deb files, there are tools to convert .deb to tar balls which you can then extract, or .deb may actually already be a tgz format file (I don't recall) that you can extract using `tar xvzf linux-image-x-y-z.deb`

If you use `apt-get source` you will find tarballs in your working directory after `apt-get` completes. These can be extracted the same way with `tar`

That will get you configuration options. To get compile-time flags, you should use the same extracted .deb source package or tarball and look through the flat text files to find `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` in the file that performs the build. Try `find . -type f -exec grep -Hn CFLAGS {} \;`